# $_ possui algum significado em questão?

Tags: php, variáveis-globais, variáveis-de-ambiente

Em "blocos de execução" vejo muito `$_SESSION` para validação de formulários e afins, mas não entendi muito bem o que exatamente significa.

Comment: Sua pergunta é sobre a variável global `$_SESSION` ou sobre o prefixo `$_`?

Comment: Bom, no caso os dois

Comment: @Problemático Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver pontuação suficiente).

Answer (score 5):

Essas são variáveis pré-definidas, conforme consta na [documentação](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.php). Elas são preenchidas pela máquina virtual de execução do PHP conforme o contexto de execução, então elas são como objetos internos expostas para seu código acessar.

É um modelo simples e útil, mas se fosse hoje duvido que a linguagem usaria algo assim, visto que a linguagem está em mutação para ser mais *enterprise* e menos de *script*, onde o contexto cabia.

Especificamente a `$_SESSION` guarda um código único que indica qual é a sessão ativa, assim é possível um *script* identificar que a chamada dele ainda faz parte de uma execução de uma mesma sessão de algum usuário e pode assim dar continuidade ao que fazia nas execuções anteriores. A web é *stateless*, então ela não guarda a situação entre uma chamada e outra, o seu código tem que lidar com isso, e um identificador de sessão é a forma de saber qual é a sessão, geralmente ela é passada entre o navegador e o servidor HTTP por *cookies*.

Outros *cookies* podem ser acessados pela variável `$_COOKIE`. Dados vindo do navegador podem ser pegos pelas `$_GET`, `$_POST`, e `$_FILES` para pegar arquivos sendo subidos, ou ainda `$_SERVER` para dados do ambiente de execução específico e da chamada, ou `$_ENV` para o ambiente geral

`$_REQUEST` é indiferente entre o *get* e *post*, e pode ser usado quando não importa a forma que veio a requisição.

Entre algumas outras, até com padrões um pouco diferentes, ainda tem a `$GLOBALS` para guardar valores acessíveis por toda execução do *script* (que costuma ser muito rápida).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 2):

### As variáveis superglobais

Essas variáveis são superglobais, e como o próprio nome diz, o seu escopo é global, ou seja, elas podem ser acessíveis a partir de qualquer lugar do código. Em relação ao nome começar com $_ não tem um propósito, é só um padrão de nome para esse tipo de variável.

O PHP possui as seguintes variáveis superglobais:

- **$_POST:** Contém os dados de uma requisição HTTP post.
- **$_GET:** Contém os dados de uma requisição HTTP get.
- **$_SESSION:** Armazena os dados da sessão.
- **$_COOKIE:** Armazena os dados dos cookies.
- **$_FILES:** Armazena as informações sobre um arquivo enviado via upload.
- **$_REQUEST:** Armazena os dados de uma requisição, podendo ser post ou get.
- **$_SERVER:** Contém informações do contexto e ambiente onde o script esta sendo executado.
- **$_ENV:** Contém variáveis de ambiente colocadas através da função [putenv](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.putenv.php). Os valores obtidos com $_ENV também podem ser obtidos pela função [getenv](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.getenv.php).

Answer (score -3):

Sempre que encontrar variáveis que começam com $_ significa que são variáveis super globais, ou seja, são variáveis especiais que podem ser usadas em qualquer parte do seu projeto, e cada uma delas tem uma função específica.

Por exemplo $_SESSION['exemplo'] cria uma sessão, $_GET pega os valores das variaveis da URL...etc...

[Clique aqui para saber mais a respeito.](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.variables.superglobals.php)